# Selecting an XPath child node without the parent namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I do not work with XML often and have never used XPath. I am trying to parse an xml document using python/lxml, using XPath. lxml relies on libxml2, and thus I do not have access to XPath 2.0 features. I am trying to do this using a list of XPaths provided by a client that have no namespaces included.

These are for a RETS server response from the Canadian Real Estate Association, if that helps. Their documentation is here: http://www.crea.ca/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/DDFDataFeedTechnicalDoc-2016-3.pdf

The paths are formatted like the following (there are many more of them):

```
Building/SizeInterior
Land/SizeTotal
```

The parent element has the namespace "`urn:CREA.Search.Property`" as seen in the following example response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RETS ReplyCode="0" ReplyText="Operation successful">
   <COUNT Records="1" />
   <RETS-RESPONSE xmlns="urn:CREA.Search.Property">
      <Pagination>
         <TotalRecords>1</TotalRecords>
         <Limit>100</Limit>
         <Offset>1</Offset>
         <TotalPages>1</TotalPages>
         <RecordsReturned>1</RecordsReturned>
      </Pagination>
      <PropertyDetails ID="XXXXXXXXXX" LastUpdated="Sun, 12 Jun 2016 14:21:20 GMT">
         <Building>
            <SizeInterior />
            <Type>No Building</Type>
            <UtilityWater>Private Utility</UtilityWater>
         </Building>
         <Land>
            <SizeTotal>0.28 ac|under 1 acre</SizeTotal>
            <SizeTotalText>0.28 ac|under 1 acre</SizeTotalText>
            <AccessType>Easy access</AccessType>
            <Acreage>false</Acreage>
            <SizeIrregular>0.28</SizeIrregular>
         </Land>
      </PropertyDetails>
   </RETS-RESPONSE>
</RETS>
```

I need to be able to grab those elements without having to modify the XPaths if possible.

What I've found so far seems to suggest that even if the namespace is only explicitly specified on a parent element, I need to specify if for every child in the path, rendering the paths provided by my client only usable if I process them to include the namespace before each element.

Is that correct or is there a way that would be cleaner? This strikes me as messy: if the children don't have a namespace explicitly assigned to them, why would the XPath *have* to be explicit about it?

I assume I'm missing something.

Comment: Elements inherit the namespace from their parents.

Comment: @choroba, I know. What I don't understand is why the inherited namespace needs to be declared for every child in the XPath.

Since we know that namespaces are inherited in a document, why can't I specify a path where the parent element includes a namespace, and the children do not (i.e. xpath would assume inheritence).

From what I can find online, it seems that's not possible, but it strikes me as odd. So I figured I'd ask.

Comment: It's possible: `<n:b xmlns:n="http://uri"><c/></n:b>`. Now, `//c` finds `c`, even if its parent's namespace is `n`.

Comment: @choroba, it doesn't seem to be working for me :( For example, this works: `tree.xpath('p:RETS-RESPONSE/p:PropertyDetails/p:Land', namespaces={'p': 'urn:CREA.Search.Property'})` but this doesn't: `tree.xpath('p:RETS-RESPONSE/p:PropertyDetails//Land', namespaces={'p': 'urn:CREA.Search.Property'})`

Comment: Similarly, `tree.xpath('//Land')` doesn't work either.

Comment: In the XML you posted, the namespace was inherited, so you have to specify it. In my sample, it wasn't.

Comment: Ok. I guess I need to read more about namespace inheritance in XML! So, would you say I have to modify those paths provided by the client to include the namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said much about your technology constraints. If you are able to use an XPath 2.0 processor, then you should be able to define the "default namespace for elements and types" as `urn:CREA.Search.Property`, and paths using unprefixed names like `Building/SizeInterior` then treat the element names as being in this namespace.

(The reason that XPath doesn't treat `n:aaa/bbb` as meaning `n:aaa/n:bbb` is that it's quite legitimate to have a no-namespace element `bbb` as a child of a namespaced element `n:aaa`).

Comment: I got really excited about your response, and then realized that I'm using lxml, which relies on libxml2, which doesn't support XPath 2.0. I'll add that to the original question.